# How did Anakin posess the ability to have dreams that tell the future?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

As the title says;
**How did Anakin posess the ability to have dreams that tell the future? Also, do any other Jedi (or Sith) have this ability or is it rare?**

Comment: George Lucas was influenced by Dune (so some say)

Comment: Other powerful force users seem to see the future in visions during meditation rather than dreams; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_vision/Canon

Comment: his dreams seem to be emotionally based, which heightens his force abilities it appears, while yoda, appears to meditate to gleen info from the future.

Comment: @Himarm The problem with the non meditating visions is as always the dark side of the force. Thus during a vision it can become clouded by your emotions (fears to be more exact). Yoda indicates that a few times as far as I'm aware. Once in episode 3 even and also in the series.

Answer (score 5):

Sudden and unexplained visions of the future are consistent within a Jedi's realm of power, and we need look no further than Anakin's own son.

We see this power in The Empire Strikes Back, when Luke is focused deeply on his training, and suddenly recieves a vision of his friends in desperate need and pain.

In fact, Darth Vader was doing this *by design*, because he knew that inflicting pain on his loved ones would cause him to have these visions, almost as if he'd experienced something similar...

In short, it's entirely possible for a Jedi to recieve sudden visions when their loved ones are going through turmoil, and apparently hereditary that a Skywalker will immediately go out and try to do something about it, even if it isn't entirely wise to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Prophetic dreams appear to be relatively common among powerful Jedi. In addition to Anakin's dreams in Episode II, we also see Ahsoka having what appears to be a similar dream-vision (of Aurra Sing still being alive) in the Clone Wars episode "[Assassin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin_%28episode%29)".

It's especially notable that Master Yoda doesn't seem *surprised* at this and merely advises her to meditate on her vision in order to gain additional clarity:

> **Yoda :** *Troubled you are, padawan?*
>
> **Ahsoka :** *Yes, master Yoda. I've been having dreams.*
>
> **Yoda :** *Dreams, you say?*
>
> **Ahsoka :** *Yes, dreams. Or visions. I don't know. But they're so real.*
>
> **Yoda :** *Premonitions. Telling you something they are.*
>
> **Ahsoka :** *I know I reported otherwise, but I believe that Aurra Sing isn't dead. She's still alive, and she's preparing to kill
>   someone close to me.*
>
> **Yoda :** *So you begin to see the true power of the force. Visions they are. Underestimate them, You must not. Meditate to see clearly.*